# Does this series have a region of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}$$
I was working on this series from the UKMT website. I solved it to get the two roots. 
(1 + sqr5)/2 (Golden ratio number).

Now I am asking myself what assumptions did I make in this calculation? Does the series converge, absolutely and what is the region then of convergence?

Comment: At the very least, you're assuming that the limit exists.

Comment: If you assume that the nth term is golden ratio to some power, can you inductively prove that this is correct? Then you can prove the limit exists

Comment: If you consider it as the limit of the sequence $$\sqrt{1}, \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1}}, \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1}}},\dots$$ then since the sequence is clearly increasing it's enough to show that it is bounded above.

Comment: What series are you talking about? Do you have a power series secluded behind the curtain?

Comment: "region of convergence" doesn't make sense for an expression without a variable in it somewhere.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255364/crazy-iterated-square-roots and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888130/equality-of-two-iterated-square-roots

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132412/is-there-an-explicit-formula-that-gives-the-value-of-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-c/2132529 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005434/possible-values-of-infinitely-nested-square-root-n-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sq and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654478/calculate-limit-0f-nested-square-roots

Comment: Please try to engage with the comments, Waitara.

Comment: Are you still here, Waitara?

Comment: Sorry my sabaticle! very helpful indeed Gerry! Links very helpful,still on it,  looks like we need 1 in the nested roots, otherwise convergence not guaranteed!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be our sequence.

Thus, $a_1=1,$ $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+a_n}$, $a_n\geq1$ and by your work we obtain:
$$\left|a_n-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|=\left|\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|=\frac{\left|1+a_{n-1}-\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{\left|a_{n-1}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}}+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}\leq\frac{\left|a_{n-1}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|}{\sqrt{2}+\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}\leq\frac{1}{3}\left|a_{n-1}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{3^2}\left|a_{n-2}-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|\leq...\leq\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}\left|a_1-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right|\rightarrow0,$$
which says that indeed $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}.$$

Comment: so if we call the limit, some value, K, then a general relation K = (1 + K) ^1/2 must be satisfied. Next, we could use inductive methods as George suggests above right?

Comment: @Waitara Mburu It works for your problem, but we need to release this way. I showed another idea.